# Drag without scrolling on a jQueryUI sortable element

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

If I have a fixed-height div with sortable elements and if I drag one to a list below, the div will scroll. I thought I might be able to set overflow: hidden, which hides the scroll bar but still scrolls the div.

**It is much easier to describe in this fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/PrZNr/2/

If I try to drag A1 under B1, the div will scroll which could be frustrating to a user. How might I prevent this behavior?

```
<div id="items">
    <ul class="sort">
        <li>Item A1</li>
        <li>Item A2</li>
        <li>Item A3</li>
        <li>Item A4</li>
        <li>Item A5</li>
        <li>Item A6</li>
        <li>Item A7</li>
        <li>Item A8</li>
        <li>Item A9</li>
        <li>Item A10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<ul class="sort">
    <li>Item B1</li>
    <li>Item B2</li>
    <li>Item B3</li>
    <li>Item B4</li>
    <li>Item B5</li>
</ul>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('.sort').sortable({
        connectWith: '.sort',
        start: function() {
            $('#items').css({
                overflow: 'hidden'
            });
        },
        stop: function() {
            $('#items').css({
                overflow: 'auto'
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you need `#items .sort` to be sortable at all or is it just a source for draggable things that are going to the other list?

Comment: Yes, it also needs to be sortable

Answer (score 7):

Well, somehow I overlooked the obvious: "scroll" option
I simply need to set scroll to false...

http://jsfiddle.net/PrZNr/3/

Comment: In my situation that is OK, but I found a lot of bugs when using the scroll option, it causes other connected lists to not work correctly. Even the fiddle does not appear to work correctly. If for instance you try to drag A1, below B1. I must have overlooked that somehow. Either way scroll has been to buggy to rely upon.

Comment: @ActionOwl: I looked at your example in JSfiddle. Vertical scrollbar disappeared perfectly.

But, when I try to drag elements, I can still see the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the screen. How can I remove that without setting the "overflow" property of the container (page itself) to hidden?

Comment: @Ishita, you can wrap the lists in a container and use the containment option to prevent the element from dragged around which gives you the horizontal scrollbar. Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/PrZNr/103/